# Allowed error in baud rate between pic and Bluetooth module

Tags: pic, bluetooth, baudrate

I'm trying to connect a dsPIC33FJ128MC804 - 16 bit pic - with a Bluetooth module 
the problem is i have few baud rates of Bluetooth to choose between them , searched the net but could not find the allowed baud rate error due to baud rate generator register takes only integer values as you know , so what is the maximum allowed error ? 
Edit: i read the related section of data sheet and family reference to UART but i do not think i found any information regarding this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, the *total* error between a transmitter and a receiver cannot exceed ±5% — half a bit time either way after a total of 10 bit times. Splitting this evenly between the two, and making allowances for crystal errors, synchronizer delays, etc., we usually say that each device needs to be within ±2% of the nominal frequency.

Comment: how the Bluetooth module will have an error? it has specific baud rate that i wanna match it with the pic

Comment: @MohamedOsama: How do you know that it doesn't? Maybe its designer was working under constraints similar to what you have!

Comment: But i mean in case of pic i put in the baud register and equation , that's way i get it not 100% but the designer of the Bluetooth did not say about its error or i am mistaken ?

Comment: I have no way of knowing, since you never told us which module you're using. But it doesn't matter anyway -- as I said at the start, this is just a generic rule of thumb. For a more detailed discussion, see the duplicate question link above. But if you just want to argue, you want room 12A, next door. ;-)